# Página PHP sem cor de fundo no Internet Explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer

Estou com um problema em abrir uma página PHP no Internet Explorar. Ele retira-me as cores de fundo.

No Google Chrome abre todas as páginas normalmente.

```
<table style="width:100%;height:100%;" bgcolor="#4682B4" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr><td></td></tr></table></div>
 <input value="Procurar" name="IWBUTTON2" type="Submit" class="IWBUTTON2CSS" id="IWBUTTON2" tabindex="21">
```

Comment: Esse código colado é a sua página completa?

Comment: É um exemplo do que me aparece em branco quando devia ter a cor azul. Funciona no google chrome e no internet explorer não

Comment: e se definires a cor de fundo no `style` não resolve? Ou ainda não experimentas te?

Comment: Sim, mas é o HTML completo ou só o trecho relativo? Use a propriedade `background-color` dentro do `style`.

Comment: São dois trechos relativos. 
E com o Internet explorar as imagens ficam todas cheias de pixeis e no Chrome está tudo bom

Comment: Colocando o style no fundo não funciona tambem

Comment: O seu html pode estar incompleto, tenta finalizar o seu SUBMIT assim: `<input value="Procurar" name="IWBUTTON2" type="Submit" class="IWBUTTON2CSS" id="IWBUTTON2" tabindex="21"/>` e vê se isso resolve

Comment: Defina a cor dentro do style, ou então no arquivo CSS. Acho que vai funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar o style background-color

```
<table style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#4682B4;" bgcolor="#4682B4" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Outra coisa...

A div que fecha logo depois da tag  me parece não estar sendo aberta. Geralmente o Google Chrome fecha automaticamente as tags para você por isso está funcionando.

Comment: Mesmo com esse codigo não funciona. 
No Chrome funciona tudo muito bem e no IE tudo mal. Até as imagens aparecem desfocadas.

Comment: posta o código inteiro aqui.

Comment: O codigo todo é muito extenso.
http://jsfiddle.net/BKhLY/1/ 
Fica aqui.. Esse retangulo central aparece em branco no IE